# Replace javascript href content with php link

Tags: javascript, php

I need to replace one link from javascript with php link.

javascript line:

```
'<a href="' + res.attachment.guid + '" target="_blank">
```

php :

```
echo '<a href="' . wp_get_attachment_url($value->ID)  . '" target="_blank">
```

javascript context:

```js
if (res.success) {
  $('.no_file_upload').remove();
  var template = '<li class="attachment-' + res.attachment.ID + '">' +
    '<p>' + res.attachment.post_title + '<span>' +
    '<a href="' + res.attachment.guid + '" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-cloud-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>' +
    '<a href="#" data-post-id="' + res.attachment.ID + '" data-project-id="' + res.attachment.project_id + '" data-file-name="' + res.attachment.post_title + '" class="delete-attach-file"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" data-post-id="' + res.attachment.ID + '" data-project-id="' + res.attachment.project_id + '" data-file-name="' + res.attachment.post_title + '"></i></a>' +
    '</p></span>' +
    '<span>' + res.attachment.post_date + '</span>' +
    '</li>';
```

I tried this way but fail:

```
<?php echo '<a href="' . wp_get_attachment_url($value->ID)  . '" target="_blank"> ?>
```

So my Wordpress site is uploading all the files to Amazon S3 using WP Offload S3 Lite plugin. I had to alter some of the template files to manage to show the proper Amazon S3 link on website, I had change href links with wp_get_attachment_url($value->ID).  The only thing left is one javascript file with that content that is still loading wrong download link. I need to make it work.

Comment: I cannot guess what you mean. Can you show input and expected output?

Comment: ya same here, please explain

Comment: I need to get the download link from another location, I don't know how to do it, the proper location is wp_get_attachment_url($value->ID) while javascript is getting the href from guid.

Comment: got that, i think you just want correct image link

Comment: That's right...

Answer (score 0):

1. I think better you use file name instead of attachment url. get_attached_file( $data->ID )
   https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_attached_file/
2. also you can use https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/ for correct url

for 1.
when you have file name you can generate your own link with a custom function.
Please let me know if there is any issue.

Comment: I already use WP Offload S3 Lite, that's the main reason I need that because its not fully compatible with my template, the files uploaded directly on website doesn't show the proper Cloudfront link but to website Wordpress upload folder path. I had to work trough the template files and alter href content with wp_get_attachment_url($value->ID). Now its fine, the only problem left is that javascript file line, right after upload the javascript is generating wrong server upload path. I need to make it work with wp_get_attachment_url($value->ID) , I don't know how to do it.

Comment: also the response please

Comment: I don't understand. To make it more clear : After I upload a test file on website I need to get the download link so people can download the file, the javascript is producing /wp-content/uploads/file.zip while it should be https://d1irz0olp0fc.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/file.zip   , after I refresh the page template php file is doing the proper job loading the cloudfront link but right after upload (page did't auto refresh) the javascript is showing the wrong path /wp-content/uploads/file.zip I need to fix that

Comment: aahh got that, please add cloudfront link to javascript,   ok let me explain you are using res.attachment.guid in href tag, please add one more variable in javascript, let it   var cfurl = 'https://d1irz0olp0fc.cloudfront.net/', now you can use '<a href="' + cfurl  + res.attachment.guid + '" target="_blank">. Hope this will help, also let me know if i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

javascript line

```
<a href="' + cloudfront_url + res.attachment.guid + '" target="_blank">
```

Complete Javascript

```
var cloudfront_url = 'https://your_unique_id.cloudfront.net/'
if (res.success) {
  $('.no_file_upload').remove();
  var template = '<li class="attachment-' + res.attachment.ID + '">' +
    '<p>' + res.attachment.post_title + '<span>' +
    '<a href="' + cloudfront_url + res.attachment.guid + '" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-cloud-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>' +
    '<a href="#" data-post-id="' + res.attachment.ID + '" data-project-id="' + res.attachment.project_id + '" data-file-name="' + res.attachment.post_title + '" class="delete-attach-file"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" data-post-id="' + res.attachment.ID + '" data-project-id="' + res.attachment.project_id + '" data-file-name="' + res.attachment.post_title + '"></i></a>' +
    '</p></span>' +
    '<span>' + res.attachment.post_date + '</span>' +
    '</li>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to mix Javascript & PHP code. That is possible but let me explain how it works. PHP code is executed on server side & Javascript is executed on client side.
So, if you write down any php code in the javacsript code, it'll be executed at the time the HTML page is sent by the server to the user. Once the page is loaded, you can't call any PHP function inside the javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code is executed in the server before executing the JavaScript client side, the only way in your case is by using AJAX call to get the download link from the server.
In the other hand, there is an option to write JavaScript inside PHP, but not the inverse.